# How to perform a result limit by using distinct values in a specific column?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Given I have this data-set.

```
Player         Team         Date_Played
John Smith     New York     2/25/2014
Joe Smith      New York     2/25/2014
Steve Johnson  New York     2/25/2014
Steph Curry    Orlando      2/25/2014
Frank Anthony  Orlando      2/26/2014
Brian Smith    Bulls        2/26/2014
Steve Johnson  Bulls        2/27/2014
Steph Curry    Bulls        2/28/2014
Ben Smith      Bulls        3/28/2014
```

I would like to know how to write a query that returns half the number of Players per Team. I would like it to look like this:

```
Player         Team         Date_Played
John Smith     New York     2/25/2014
Joe Smith      New York     2/25/2014
Steph Curry    Orlando      2/25/2014
Brian Smith    Bulls        2/26/2014
Steve Johnson  Bulls        2/27/2014
```

I've considered trying to use the LIMIT or TOP commands but I don't how to write a query to limit the results based on distinct values in a specific column. 
Any ideas? Is this possible?

Comment: Why PL/SQL? This could be done in an simple SQL query.

Comment: Which half? Why John and Joe but not Steve?

Comment: @wolφi It appears to be a common misconception that PL/SQL is the same as "SQL using an Oracle database" rather than meaning "Procedural Language extension for SQL in Oracle Relational Databases" so questions often get mistagged - just correct the tags/title to remove inappropriate references to PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the corrections @MT0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions.  I would use `row_number()` and `count()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by team) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by team order by team) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 0.5 * cnt;
```

There are other methods using a single function, such as `ntile()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, 
             ntile(2) over (partition by team order by team) as tile
      from t
     ) t
where tile = 1;
```

Or `percentile()` or others.